# Copy-Paste Interaction Not Working in FormBuilderTextField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

I'm facing an issue with the **`FormBuilderTextField`** widget in Flutter. I want to enable copy-paste interaction within the **`FormBuilderTextField`** when I long-press it, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's my code:

```
FormBuilderTextField(
  name: 'pincode',
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: primaryColor,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {},
  maxLength: 6,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
    counterText: "",
    border: buildBorderDecoration(),
    enabledBorder: buildEnableAndDisabledBorder(),
    errorBorder: buildErrorBorder(),
    disabledBorder: buildEnableAndDisabledBorder(),
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    filled: true,
    labelText: '680024',
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: lightGrey,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Despite setting **`enableInteractiveSelection`** to **`true`**, the copy-paste interaction is not working. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

- Flutter version: 3.10.2
- Operating System: Windows
- Any other relevant details or code snippets.

Please let me know if you have any insights or solutions to this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would seem this issue was known already.

Refer to this [github link](https://github.com/flutter-form-builder-ecosystem/flutter_form_builder/issues/1202#issuecomment-1491463576) with the potential solution which is to add *contextMenuBuilder* to *FormBuilderTextField*.

```
FormBuilderTextField(
  name: "description",
  contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.editableText(
        editableTextState: editableTextState,
    );
 }, 
);
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, But it's not worked in my case, It seems I have a Listener widget around the Scaffold beneath the MaterialApp, intending to manage keyboard unfocusing, and this is making the issue, while I try to copy-past something into the field, before executing the past functionality keyboard unFocus function executing at first so the context to the active field is loosing while there. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Good to see you solved it. I mostly wrap the parent widget in a GestureDetector and in the onTap method call the unfocus. This hasn't interfered with contextual actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Solved**:

It appears that I have wrapped a Listener widget around the Scaffold beneath the MaterialApp, intending to manage keyboard unfocusing. However, this setup is causing an issue. When I attempt to paste something into a text field, the keyboard unfocus function is executed prematurely, resulting in the loss of context for the active field. This sequence disrupts the intended paste functionality, making it challenging to interact seamlessly with the text fields.

```
Listener(
          onPointerDown: (_){
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          },
          child: ScaffoldMessenger(
            key: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: ref.watch(avoidBottomInsetProvider),
              body: child,
            ),
          ),
        );
```

So I removed the Listener on top of the Scaffold and added onTapOutside to FormbuilderTextField.

```
onTapOutside: (event)=>FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
```